# RXJS: How do I utilize the emitted observable at the end of the processing stream?

Tags: rxjs

Say I have a function `generateIdUpdate` which uses an id observable to load the addresses of the person belonging to the id. I want to set an instance variable holding the selected id upon successful completion of address loading. What is the best way to do that?

Also, is this a reflection of bad design (that is, having one function load addresses **and** update a stateful field at the end)?

```
export class TapTest {
  private selectedId: number;
  private id$: Observable<number> = ...;
  
  generateIdUpdate$(): Observable<PersonAddress> {
    return id$.pipe(
      // switchMap in case a new Id is selected while loading
      switchMap(id => loadPerson(id)),
      // Get the observable of addresses
      mergeMap((person: Person) => loadAddresses(person)), 
      tap(
        // since this completed successfully, set the selectedId field to the id
      )
    );
  }

  loadPerson(id: number) : Person { ... }
  loadAddresses(person: Person) : Observable<PersonAddress> { ... }
}
```

Given the following function which attempts to get the emitted id, load the person, load the addresses and return them, but also to update the stateful id of the person upon address load into the instance variable, what is the proper way to "carry through" the id through the processing stream?

Answer (score 1):

If I uderstand correctly what you want to do, I would approach the problem in a very similar manner as what you have described, with some little variations (see my comments)

```
export class TapTest {
  private selectedId: number;
  private id$ = ...;
  
  generateIdUpdate$(): Observable<PersonAddress> {
    return id$.pipe(
      // switchMap in case a new Id is selected while loading
      // loadPerson is a function that returns an Observable and not a function
     // that returns a Person as in your original example
     // otherwise switchMap will not work and actually will not even compile
      switchMap(id => loadPerson(id)),
      // Get the observable of addresses
      // Rather than mergemap I would use concatMap, which basically means
      // "wait until I complete before processing the next notification of my
      // upstream Observable" 
      concatMap((person: Person) => loadAddresses(person)), 
      tap(
        // since this completed successfully, set the selectedId field to the id
        // the tap operator expects a an Observer as input parameter
        // an Observer is an object with 3 properties, next, error and complete
        // each of these property is optional
        // in this case we will define the next property as a function that expexts
        // the notification as input - in pour case we will use the input to set
        // the instance variable selectedId
        {
           next: (id) => this.selectedId = id
        }
      )
    );
  }

  // loadPerson must return an Observable<Person> for the above code to work
  loadPerson(id: number) : Person { ... }

  loadAddresses(person: Person) : Observable<PersonAddress> { ... }
}
```

You could move the `tap` operator at the beginning of the `pipe` if you want to store the `selectedId` regardless of the successful completion of `loadAddress`.

Comment: this does not work for me: the `next` function casts id to the PersonAddress type. So... it appears that the next parameter is expecting a function that takes `PersonAddress` as the initial argument, not number. The id$ observable is a number, btw. I'll clarify that in the code.